# TopoJson and ChartGeo/ChartJS: Unexpected geomerty

Tags: javascript, json, geometry, chart.js, topojson

I'm current working with TopoJson and ChartJS to draw map of the UK (which I have done successfully).
Now I want to simply draw two squares off the west coast of GB but I have been rather unsuccessful in this endeavour.

Below is my (custom writen) TopoJson data:

```js
const topoData = {
    type: "Topology",
    arcs:
    [
        [[0,0],[-50,0],[0,50],[50,0],[0,-50]]
    ],
    objects: {
        locs: {
            type: "GeometryCollection",
            geometries: [
            {
                arcs: [[0]],
                type: "Polygon",
                properties: {
                    Name: "Other Regions"
                }
            }]
        }
    },
};
```

From all the materials I have gathered, the points defined in the arcs object should draw a simple 50x50 square but it doesn't; instead it draws this:
[Incorrectly drawn geo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3GfI.png)

I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so, I just figured it out. The docs are, rather frustratingly, incorrect. They state that the vertices should be be declared as deltas from the previous vertex but that is wrong!

**The vertices should be defined as actual positions!**